# SOAPUI What causes "error in msg parsing: xml was empty, didn't parse!"

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, httpd, lua

Currently, I have a structure which takes a SOAP request, fires the request at a reverse proxy (a script written in Lua) which takes a copy of the SOAP request and then passes that to the webserver, and I get some SOAP response.

Without the reverse proxy, the request works fine and I get the expected response, however once I add in the reverse proxy (which I currently only want to use to get a copy of the SOAP request and save it to a file), I get a SOAP response which tells me "error in msg parsing: xml was empty, didn't parse!".

Interestingly, the localhost which the reverse proxy redirects the request to, is still live and I can see it on the browser. This suggests to me that the request is passed through the reverse proxy and the webserver interacts with it, however the response from it somehow goes missing.

Is there a way I can try debug this to see what the input and output messages of the SOAP endpoint or reverse proxy and can anyone explain why the SOAP response is doing what it does?